# R list.files/file.exists and env variable HOMEDRIVE issue on Windows

Tags: r, windows, environment-variables

I'm running some code from a CRAN package that checks to see if a file exists.

The full file reference is provided as paste0(Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH"), "Something.json"). This works for myself and many others, but not all.

We've checked that Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH") correctly evaluates to "\Users\username" and Sys.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") is "C:" and the file exists.

Yet for some reason, list.files("\Users\username") provides the correct listing of files at "C:\Users\username" for only some of us. It shows an empty vector for others even though list.files("C:\Users\username") works.

Any idea what could be causing this? the HOMEDRIVE variable is not being changed during execution. I'm hoping there's some other global variable or setting that could get this to work. I preferably don't want to add any custom changes to the package code to make this work for us - and I don't even know how to do that. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Try `file.path(Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH"), "Something.json")`

Comment: R will treat `~` as an alias for a users home directory. What about `list.files("~")` or `readLines("~/Something.json")`. What package is this specifically? Can you provide any sort of reproducible example with code we can run to see what's really happening?

Comment: Hi - the package in this case is irrelevant as it's specifically base R and is a problem outside of the specific function call. list.files(Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH")) doesn't work for my coworker and has an empty list, but list.files(paste0(Sys.getenv("HOMEDRIVE"), Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH"))) provides a list of the files expected. The same thing happens with file.exists(paste0(Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH"), "File Name.json") which is more similar to the code that is failing for me in the package

Comment: The actual function I'm having issues with is in paws, in the sso_credential_process function. It uses these lines with no reference to Sys.getenv("HOMEDRIVE").    json_file <- paste0(cache_key, ".json")
  root <- ifelse(Sys.info()[[1]] == "Windows", Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH"), "~")
  sso_cache <- file.path(root, ".aws", "sso", "cache", json_file)
  if (!file.exists(sso_cache)) {

Comment: Looks like you've already raised an issue with the package provider: https://github.com/paws-r/paws/issues/640. Their code does look incorrect for Windows machines.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes I did - I just assumed I was missing something and the package was right. :)